# Objective-C WKWebView does not expose scrollView as per Class documentation

Tags: objective-c, macos, scrollview, wkwebview

Documentation shows `scrollView` property but cannot access in code.

I get this error:

> .../MasterViewController.m:106:20: Property 'scrollView' not found on object of type 'WKWebView *'

Any ideas?

This is for OS X not iOS; sorry about the tag before.

the .h file-

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@import WebKit;
#import <WebKit/WebFrameLoadDelegate.h>

@interface MasterViewController : NSViewController

@property (strong) WKWebView *buildLog;
```

the .m file code-

```
self.buildLog.scrollView setContentOffset:100 animated:YES];
...l/MasterViewController.m:126:20: Property 'scrollView' not found on object of type 'WKWebView *'
```

Comment: Are you compiling for iOS (as the tag implies) or Mac OS X (as `NSViewController` and `Cocoa/Cocoa.h` imply)?

Answer (score 1):

The `scrollView` property is only part of the *iOS* version of `WKWebView`.

On OS X this is simply not available. It may be more an internal implementation detail there. You can probably find the NSScrollView by walking the `WKWebView` child views, but this is a bit of a grey area that may break at one point.